# How Do I Refresh A Notebook?

Tags: notebooks

I am hard at work on a lengthy and complicated notebook. Couple of days ago I pulled down on the evaluation menu. I should have selected 'Evaluate Notebook'. Unfortunately, by mistake I left clicked on 'Analyze Notebook'. Now I'm left with an error message in red ink at the top of the notebook. How do I make the error message disappear?

Comment: I don't see any "Analyze Notebook" button in my installation. Which version are you running?

Comment: @LukasLang - Starting in version 12.3 the `Evaluation` menu includes a section containing `Analyze Notebook` and `Analyze Cells`. However, the [`Guide for the Evaluation Menu`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationMenu.html) does not reflect this and I have been unable to locate any documentation on these.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! I checked in the latest version, but it looks like I have a customized menu based on a previous version... Now I can also see it :)

Comment: @AlaJam Can you try to evaluate `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] = Inherited` in the affected notebook?

Comment: Mister LL: I am not finding your message on any of my pull down menus. (I'm on 12.3.1). When I first open the notebook I get the message about unsafe content and so I have to enable dynamic content. My error message is in blurred (overlapping letters) red ink. At the far right hand side I read: NotebookObject Method->Queued